# GitHub Pages site is not displaying the actual site instead its displaying some react instructions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please help, I deployed my React App to GitHub Pages and it went live for some time and then it started showing these react instructions(check the attached screenshot)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/makhosi6/my_projects_links/master/site.png  (Image)
https://makhosi6.github.io/movie-app/ (Site)

Comment: this is not react instructions. this seems like you've created the react app using creat-react-app command and the instructions are the default readme file that is generated by automatically.

Comment: I think you should create a build and upload that build into the repository.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have crashed.  The process is no longer running.  You'll need to start it again by running `npm start`.

It will do that every time it crashes, so if you want the app to stay up for longer you should read about getting it ready for deployment here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#other-solutions